# PHP - Parse an array string into multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, parsing

i'm starting learning php. I have an array :

```
array (size=24)
0 => string 'Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain' (length=34)
1 => string 'Paris, 343 boulevard Saint-Germain' (length=35)
2 => string 'Marseille, 343 boulevard Camille Flammarion' (length=44)
3 => string 'Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins' (length=37)
4 => string 'Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens' (length=34)
5 => string 'Paris, 12 rue des singes' (length=25)
6 => string 'Paris, 34 quai VoLtAiRe' (length=24)
7 => string 'Paris, 34 rue Voltaire' (length=23)
8 => string 'Lille, 120 boulevard Victor Hugo' (length=33)
9 => string 'Marseille, 50 rue Voltaire' (length=27)
10 => string 'Toulouse, 90 rue Voltaire' (length=26)
...
```

What i'd like to do, is parse each string element into var like :

```
$city = Lyon, Paris, Marseille...
$Number = 458, 343, 29..
$typeOfRoad = boulevard, rue, chemin, quaie...
$NameOfRoad = Saint-Germain, Camille Flammarion...
```

[edit] Thanks to @splash58, i fix my problem! Thanks you so much!

Thanks. :)

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: Of course i tried guys.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($input as $item) {
   // Parse string
   if (preg_match('/^(?P<city>\w+),\s+(?P<Number>\d+)\s+(?P<typeOfRoad>\w+)\s+(?P<NameOfRoad>.+)$/', $item, $m));
   // remove numerous keys
   $m = array_diff_key($m, array_flip(range(0,4)));
   // make vars
   extract($m);
   echo "$city  $Number  $typeOfRoad  $NameOfRoad\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey @splash58, thanks you very much for the regular expression! I try to solve another issue, each loop return the same result (the first address), it doesn't incremente.. how can i execut the same operation on the next string of my input array? :) thanks

Comment: it already so you ask. Look there https://eval.in/398524 and ask, if i  wrong understand

Comment: use `foreach($address` in your code

Comment: i found my problem : $address is parsed with some \r (http://www.pix-host.com/allimages/48972269.png) instead of (http://www.pix-host.com/allimages/94015808.png). Indeed, $address is already parsed from a text file with $address = preg_split("/[\r]/", $textfile); ..

Comment: And the solution was to simply parse $address with \n instead of \r

Comment: you can do `array_map('trim', $address)` which remove trailing and leading `\r`, `\n` and spaces

Answer (score 0):

try this code: ($array is the array with all the items)

```
<?php
  foreach ($array as $item) {
    /* explode in 4 segments max */
    $segment = explode(' ', $item, 4);
    $city = $segment[0];
    $number = $segment[1];
    $typeOfRoad = $segment[2];
    $nameOfRoad = $segment[3];

    /* here you can use the variables before the next loop */
    [...]
  }
?>
```

Edit: This code assume that the first, second and third variables hasn't spaces, otherwise it's imposible to delimiter.

Comment: the third parameter of explode indicates that only have 4 segments max :)

Comment: Those aren't the parameters, in the example, the first parameter has dash (Saint-Germain), the second and third parameters don't have spaces, otherwise isn't possible to do if we don't know the limits.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Lille, 120 boulevard Victor Hugo';

echo $city = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ','));
echo PHP_EOL;
$parts = explode(" ", $string);
array_shift($parts);
echo $num = $parts[0];
echo PHP_EOL;
array_shift($parts);
echo $type = $parts[0];
echo PHP_EOL;
array_shift($parts);
echo $roadName = implode($parts, " ");
echo PHP_EOL;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/4PwuWY

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression for this. It should look similar to the following:

^(.*), (\d+) (\S+) (.*)

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php